# JavaScript - create a string by combining other strings at different positions

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I have 3 strings: s1 = "ab", s2 = "cd", s3 = "ef".

The goal is to create another string by combining s1, s2, and s3. The catch is that the user can decide the positions of those 3 strings. So, for instance:

s1 - position 3;

s2 - position 2;

s3 - position 1

Result:
efcdab.

My question is, what is the best way to solve this problem? My solution was to create 3 objects that will each hold the string position and value as properties, add the objects into and array and then sort the array using the position property of each object, but I just have the feeling that there is a better solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a method?

Comment: just keep 2 arrays, one with your strings and one with which string should go in each position. In your example : [s1, s2, s3] and [3, 2, 1]. Then you can iterate your position array and concatenate to a string the corresponding string element

Comment: How is user deciding the positions? Please clarify!

Comment: let's just say that I receive an object with the following structure: 
{
value: "ab",
position: 1
} ; the value and position can be added with the use of 2 inputs and I just create those objects

Comment: @five please check my answer if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings and positions are given as an array of `{value, position}` objects, you can use `Array.reduce` to order and concatenate them to an ordered string in linear time:

```js
let strings = [
  {value: "ab", position: 3},
  {value: "cd", position: 2},
  {value: "ef", position: 1}
];

let string = strings.reduce((sorted, next) => {
  sorted[next.position - 1] = next.value;
  return sorted;
}, []).join("");

console.log(string); // "efcdab"
```

Comment: Did you choose positions randomly?

Comment: For this combination:       let strings = [
  {value: "ab", position: 1},
  {value: "cd", position: 3},
  {value: "ef", position: 0},
  {value: "gh", position: 2}
]; The result should be //efabghcd but your solution will provide different solution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PankajShukla No, you didn't miss anything, I assumed the positions indicated *source* indices, not *destination* indices. Fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Clever way of sorting, sorting nonetheless but OP can't get away with it. He has to sort. :)

Comment: @PankajShukla He has to sort, yes, but not necessarily via `Array.sort` :)

Answer (score 1):

Just giving it a try where you `strPos` is the user defined object for ordering the strings

```js
var s1 = 'ab';
var s2 = 'cd';
var s3 = 'ef';
var strs = {s1:s1,s2:s2,s3:s3};
var strPos = {1:'s1',2:'s3',3:'s2'};
var fin = '';
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
  fin += strs[strPos[i]];
}
console.log(fin);
```

@Five from your comments the answer can be changed to follow your object structure as below

```js
var definedOrderedList = [{
  value: 'ab',
  position: 2
}, {
  value: 'cd',
  position: 1
}, {
  value: 'ef',
  position: 3
}];
var strArr = [];
for (var o in definedOrderedList) {
  strArr[definedOrderedList[o].position] = definedOrderedList[o].value;
}
var finalString = strArr.join('');
console.log(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two objects. One that has string and values, lets say **values** like

```
{
  s1: 'String1',
  s2: 'String2',
  s3: 'String3'
}
```

and one lets say **position** object like

```
{
  p1: 'store user entry for position1',
  p2: 'store user entry for position2',
  p3: 'store user entry for position3'
}
```

and access first object like this values[position['p1']] add to  values[position['p2']] and so on

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you described your object structure, looks like you will have an array like this(chosen one possible random ordering):

```
var arr = [ { value: "ab", position: 2 },  { value: "cd", position: 1 },  { value: "ef", position: 3 } ];
```

Then you can sort the array based on the position and then concatenate the strings.

```js
var arr = [ { value: "ab", position: 2 },  { value: "cd", position: 1 },  { value: "ef", position: 3 } ];
arr.sort((a,b) => a.position - b.position);

var ans="";
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  ans += arr[i].value;
}
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are having them pick the order, but with this all you have to do is fill in the options for them to choose and it does the rest of the work. This can be made prettier by a lot, but that is up to you and how you take user interaction.

```
var selections = ["ab", "cd", "ef"];
var str = "";

while(selections.length){
    var choice = prompt("Type part of the string from below that you want to add first:\n " + "    " + selections);
    var index = selections.indexOf(choice);

    if(index !== -1){
        str += choice;
        selections.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

alert("You typed: " + str);
```